# Exporting API output response to CSV - Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, response, export-to-csv

I am not an expert in Python but I used it to call data from an API. I got a code 200 and printed part of the data but I am not able to export/ save/ write the output (to CSV). Can anyone assist?

This is my code:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/csv',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'
}

response = requests.get('https://feeds.preqin.com/api/investor/pe', headers=headers)
print response
output = response.content
```

And here is how the data (should be CSV, correct?) looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdpnK.jpg)

I managed to save it as txt but the output is not usable/ importable (e.g. to Excel). I used the following code:

```
text_file = open("output.txt", "w")
n = text_file.write(output)
text_file.close()
```

Thank you and best regards,

A

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text.

Comment: try using `pandas` library. create a dataframe in panda and then you can save in any format whichever you like including csv

Comment: Which attributes do I need to specify to create a pandas dataframe?I tried: 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=output)
but got an error! "DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content uses pipes `|` as a separator. CSVs use `,` commas (that's why they're called Comma Separated Values).

You can simply replace your data's pipes with commas. However, this may be problematic if the data you have itself uses commas.

```
output = response.content.replace("|", ",")
```

---

As comments have suggested, you could also use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# Get your output normally...
output = response.content

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(output), sep="|")

# Saving to .CSV
df.to_csv(r"C:\output.csv")

# Saving to .XLSX
df.to_excel(r"C:\output.xlsx")
```

Comment: It gives me the following error (using pandas):
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sep'

Comment: Edited the original code. @finconomist